# Reading logical operator from command line

Tags: c++

I am trying to read **12|11|13** from command line from my application. 
I get error "**11 is not recognozed as an internal command**" while reading this string.

I am OK if I can read complete string or individual numbers.

Can anyone suggest how to read this?

Nipun

Comment: You need to pass the args between brackets ex : myprog "11|12|14"

Comment: Explanation to Jonas' comment: The pipe symbol `|` is used to take the output from the first parameter as input for the second parameter. Since `11` isn't a valid command you get your error. @Jonas: You should post this as an answer ;).

Comment: Thanks Jonas for quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the args between quotes ex :

```
myprog "11|12|14"
```

Because if you don't, the caracter `|` (pipe) is used to pass the output from the program on left to the program on right of the symbol.